# Inconsistent Saves / 'For Later' message

Tags: discussion, user-interface, saves

When I 'save' a post in my 'For Later' list, I get the following message:

> Question saved to [For later].

But when I remove it from the list, I get:

> Question removed from saves.

---

Shouldn't the popup be consistent with the first notification, something like

> Question removed from [For later].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That doesn't seem to make much sense.

When you add a save, it makes sense that it gets assigned to a folder.

When you remove a save, it just goes.  If the message is "remove from [folder]", the meaning is ambiguous -is it just removed from that folder and does it exist elsewhere, or is it gone forever?